# Can "happy" be a verb?

Tags: adjectives

Can we say *"happy"* in sentences like "**Happy reading!**" is a verb and means *"enjoy"*? If not, what is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentence, "**Happy reading!**" is the same as "**I wish that you have happy reading!**"
The *I wish that you have* is understood. In English we say, "Happy Holidays" which means *we want you to have a* happy holiday season. We're just lazy like that!

Answer (score 5):

In:

> happy reading

"happy" is an adjective that qualifies the noun "reading". "Happy" cannot be a verb, there's no verb in that sentence but the verb "have" is implied:

> I wish you have a happy reading,

meaning : "I wish you enjoy your reading."

Answer (score 0):

No happy isn't a *verb*.  It is an *adjective*.  The fact is that the statement happy reading actually means I wish you will/did enjoy your reading...  P.S. Remember that happy isn't a verb.  It's an adjective.